# iphone touch trailing stars

Tags: iphone, animation, touch, trailing

I want to create a simliar effect for ipad in xcode as shown in following link, can any one guide.
http://tutorials.flashmymind.com/2009/04/flash-mouse-trailer-with-stars/

```
-(IBAction)SendEmail{
    MFMailComposeViewController *picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [picker setSubject:@"Hello from xCode!"];
```

Regards.

Comment: 1. What is the point of the code snippet? 2. What *exactly* do you want to do? What have you tried? What is the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Mouse trails don't even make sense on an iPad. There is no cursor.